# Is there a good way to compute this limit?

Tags: calculus

While deriving the Wallis' product $\displaystyle \prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{2n}{2n-1}\cdot\frac{2n}{2n+1}\bigg)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ by applying integration by parts on $\displaystyle I(n)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{n}x\;dx$, One obtains $\displaystyle\frac{I(2k)}{I(2k-2)}=\frac{2k-1}{2k}$ and could get $\displaystyle\frac{I(2k-1)}{I(2k)}\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{2k}{2k-1}\frac{2k-2}{2k-1}\frac{2k-2}{2k-3}\frac{2k-4}{2k-3}\cdots\frac{6}{5}\frac{4}{5}\frac{4}{3}\frac{2}{3}$.
To compute $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{I(2k-1)}{I(2k)}=\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2k-1}x\;dx}{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2k}x\;dx}$, the following could be used:
$\displaystyle I(2k+1)\leq I(2k)\leq I(2k-1)\Rightarrow1\leq\frac{I(2k)}{I(2k+1)}\leq\frac{I(2k-1)}{I(2k+1)}=\frac{2k+1}{2k}$, where the previously derived fact $\displaystyle\frac{I(2k)}{I(2k-2)}=\frac{2k-1}{2k}$ was used for the last equality, so the limit could be obtained by the squeeze theorem.
My question is, is there another way to compute $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2k-1}x\;dx}{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2k}x\;dx}$? Or more generally, is there some strategy to compute the following kind of limit $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi}(f(x))^{k-1}dx}{\int_{0}^{\pi}(f(x))^{k}dx}$? I tried L'hospital's rule and obtained $\displaystyle\frac{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2k-1} x\cdot\ln(\sin x)dx}{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2k} x\cdot\ln(\sin x) dx}$. But even if L'hospital's rule could be repeatedly applied, it didn't look helpful.

Comment: should be able to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\int_0^\pi \sin(x)^{k+1} dx}{\int_0^\pi \sin(x)^{k} dx} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{2\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 x^{k+1} dx}{2\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 x^k dx} = 1$

Comment: @user1952009 Thanks. I could compute similarly by substitution

Comment: sorry my mistake it's more $\int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon (1-x^2)^k dx$ but the idea is there : Taylor expand the function around where it is maximum (here where it is equal to $1$)

Comment: it is not so different of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method